# Swift, unwrapping nil runtime error for recording audio

Tags: ios, swift

In the following code I am getting a runtime error as you can see here in this pic:

[image]

It happens after I login into twitter, push Record button, and the push Record button in the next ViewController. I suspect the reason is that somehow audioRecorder is nil and when force-unwrapping using ! at "if self.audioRecorder!.recording", code crashes. But I can't understand why audioRecorder should be nil here. Do you guys have any ideas what am I doing wrong?
Here is the full code.
Best,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?

func setUpAudioRecorder() {
    do {
        let baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first!
        let pathComponents = [baseString, "sound.m4a"]
        let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
        try session.setActive(true)

        var recordSettings = [String : AnyObject]()
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: recordSettings)
        self.audioRecorder!.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
    } catch (_) {
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.saveButton.enabled = false
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func recordTapped(button: AnyObject) {
    if self.audioRecorder!.recording {
        self.audioRecorder!.stop()
        button.setTitle("Record", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    } else {
        do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        self.audioRecorder!.record()
        button.setTitle("Stop Recording", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } catch (_) {}
        }
    self.playButton.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure `setUpAudioRecorder` is actually being called before `recordTapped`?

Answer (score 0):

Oh boy, how right you are Rhythmic Fistman. I just called the function inside the IBOutlet and now it's working. Thank a lot for your very helpful note.
Here is the working code for anyone else interested:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder?

func setUpAudioRecorder() {
    do {
        let baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).first!
        let pathComponents = [baseString, "sound.m4a"]
        let audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker)
        try session.setActive(true)

        var recordSettings = [String : AnyObject]()
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioURL!, settings: recordSettings)
        self.audioRecorder!.meteringEnabled = true
        self.audioRecorder!.prepareToRecord()
    } catch (_) {
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.saveButton.enabled = false
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func recordTapped(button: AnyObject) {
    if (self.audioRecorder?.recording == nil || !self.audioRecorder!.recording) {
        if (self.audioRecorder?.recording == nil) {
            setUpAudioRecorder()
        }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            self.audioRecorder!.record()
            button.setTitle("Stop Recording", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        } catch (_) {}
    } else {
        self.audioRecorder!.stop()
        button.setTitle("Record", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
    self.playButton.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}